# Docker swarm high availability on nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm experimenting with docker swarm. With VirtualBox I've set up three ubuntu machines (each of them running Docker 17.12.0 CE) on my host system (windows 7).

I've created a docker swarm with the `docker swarm init` command on one of the ubuntu instances (the manager), and connected the two others as workers with the `docker swarm join` command. On the manager node I've created a service with `docker service create --name test -p 80:80 --replicas 3 myuser/webapp`.

My webapp is running fine in a container on all nodes in the swarm, and I can reach it in a browser from my host on the different ip-addresses assigned to the virtual ubuntu machines - e.g. 192.168.56.103/webapp on my worker2.

However if I shut down worker2, I obviously cant't reach it anymore. What is the best way to ensure high availability here, so that if any of the nodes are down, my webapp is still reachable?

In a live environment the question would be, how do I avoid a "single point of entry" to my application (running in a swarm), when users access it via their browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need implement a load balancer that distribute the traffic across all the instances of this service, like [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) or [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/) with docker swarm support.

#### Nginx

```
http {
  upstream webapp {
    server 192.168.56.101;
    server 192.168.56.102;
    server 192.168.56.103;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location /webapp {
      proxy_pass http://webapp;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Traefik

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  lb:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: >
      --web --docker --docker.swarmmode
      --docker.domain=example.com --docker.watch
      --logLevel=DEBUG
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
  webapp:
    image: 'myuser/webapp'
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/webapp"
        - "traefik.backend=webapp"
        - "traefik.port=80"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But wouldn't this just mean, that the load-balancer would become a single point of failure, or am I missing the point here?

Comment: That depends on the infrastructure you use, you could use [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) or [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/?nc1=h_ls) load balancers with your cluster Docker Swarm

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look into that.